# Android element ID naming

Tags: android, xml

So I have a string in my strings.xml file declared like so:

```
<string name="welcome">Please hit the menu to begin</string>
```

And I have a TextView in my main.xml that uses it like so:

```
<TextView
android:id="@string/welcome"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/welcome"
/>
```

Now, is that the proper way to give a TextView an ID? It seems strange to use a string resource as an ID like that.

Answer (score 4):

> Now, is that the proper way to give a TextView an ID?

No. Use `android:id="@+id/whatever"`.

Answer (score 1):

To add an id directly to a textview you must append a + sign

`android:id="@+id/welcome"`

alternatively you can have an id set up in a resource file

```
<resources>
  <item name="welcome" type="id"/>
</resources>

android:id="@id/welcome"
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html
is the manual page related to this topic